# date syntax is not valid, PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date

I would like to query a column name's inputdate, type : date. When I query:

```
where (inputdate>='$VEStart' AND inputdate<='$VEEnd')
```

I got:

```
error : warning pg_query() query failed error invalid input syntax for date where (inputdate>='' AND inputdate<='').
```

But when I try to replace it:

```
where (inputdate>='2015-12-01' AND inputdate<='2015-12-31')
```

It works. I thought it was a problem with variables. so I tried to echo both variables, but they display the right values. Anything wrong here?

Comment: output the `var_dump($VEStart);` and `var_dump($VEEnd);`

Comment: Your variables are empty. Before creating SQL, confirm that the variables are dates. Also use [pg_query_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) to parameterize the query

Comment: Are those PHP variables?

Comment: @Tamil I tried the var_dump it is :  string(10) "2015-12-18". Is this the error?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you cannot use variables inside strings like that when using single quotes. But in either case, you should do what @zedfoxus suggests, use parameterized queries.

Comment: try this once. `where (inputdate>='{$VEStart}' AND inputdate<='{$VEEnd}')` and @zedfoxus suggests it better way coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you an example beyond the comment, use something like this and ensure that you add improvements to the below code before putting it into production use; also test it well.

```
<?php

$VEStart = '2015-01-01';
$VEEnd = '2015-2-28';

// validate the dates
if (!isDateValid($VEStart)) {
    print "Invalid start date\n";
    return;
}
if (!isDateValid($VEEnd)) {
    print "Invalid end date\n";
    return;
}

// format the dates
$VEStart = formattedDate($VEStart);
$VEEnd = formattedDate($VEEnd);
echo sprintf ("all good - %s and %s\n", $VEStart, $VEEnd);

// see http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php
$sql = 'select ... where inputdate between $1 and $2';
$connection = pg_connect('...');
$result = pg_query_params($connection, $sql, array($VEStart, $VEEnd));
...more code...    

// ----

// add good phpdoc
// see how others add doc - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904214/what-is-the-proper-php-function-documentation-format
function formattedDate($date) {
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);
    return date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
}

// add good phpdoc
function isDateValid($date) {
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);
    return checkdate($month, $day, $year);
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. It;s inspire me a lot. The input is read as a date now